# Python List comprehension: Single string to list

Tags: python, string

I'm struggling with list comprehensions.

Basically I have a simple string:

```
string =  "['a','b','c','d']"
```

Note, that the brackets,commas and quotation marks are part of the string.
What I need is a `list1` with a,b,c,d as elements (so i need to get rid of the quotation marks, the commas and brackets.)

for entry in string:

```
list1 = [x.lstrip(" ' ") for x in string.split(',')]
list2 = [x.strip(" ' ") for x in list1]
```

This does not work at all. list1 gets created without the beginning `"'"`, but when I try to print out list2 the quotations are there again. I did not even start dealing with the brackets. 
Is there a nice way to get my list?

Comment: I prefer the usage of `ast.literal_eval`, but based on your effort it would look like this: `data = [value.strip("' ") for value in string[1:-1].split(',')]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a more pythonic way for such tasks you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) :

```
>>> s=  "['a','b','c','d']"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> list1=literal_eval(s)
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

You can also use regular expression that is more flexible and useful in other tasks :

*Note* that in this case using `literal_eval` is the pythonic way!

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+',s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string is already built as a list object but with quotation marks as you stated:

```
string =  "['a','b','c','d']"
```

You can simply make

```
exec('list1='+string)
```

---

As an alternative, you can remove everything that is not commas, and end up with

```
string = "a,b,c,d"
```

For instance

```
import re
string = re.sub(r"[^\w,]", "", string)
```

And then you use

```
>>> list1 = string.split(',')
>>> list1
['a','b','c','d']
```

Answer (score 2):

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is the way to go. It won't execute malicious code in case user modifies string to perform some kind of exploit. Check [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for additional information.

```
import ast
string =  "['a','b','c','d']"
assert ast.literal_eval(string) == ['a','b','c','d']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
In [110]: from ast import literal_eval

In [111]: li=literal_eval(string)

In [112]: li
Out[112]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [113]: type(li)
Out[113]: list
```

or alternatively Using Slicing with list comprehension

```
In [122]: li1=string[1:-1].split(',')
Out[122]: ["'a'", "'b'", "'c'", "'d'"]
In [127]: [elem.strip("'") for elem in li1]
Out[127]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or

```
In [7]: li2=list(string)

In [8]: [elem for elem in li2 if elem.isalpha()]
Out[8]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace(). try to this

```
>>> string =  "['a','b','c','d']"
>>> string.replace("'", "")
'[a,b,c,d]'
>>> print string.replace("", "")
['a','b','c','d']
>>> print string.replace("'", "")
[a,b,c,d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you desired solution I don't know the complexity of this but this is simple solution you just need to add one condition in list comprehension.

```
string =  "['a','b','c','d']"
l = [x for x in string if x not in ['"',"[","]","'",',']]
```

output would be  `l= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Note: This is just for given input, output may vary if input changed.